# Undefined Variable in View but var_dump shows data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a resource controller (CRUD actions), setup my `Route::resource('clients', 'ClientController');` and all seem to be working fine except when I use the Show method.

Visiting localhost:8000/clients/1 produced an undefined variable error for `client`.  Im not sure how or why the view is not picking up on the $client variable I am passing to it from controller.

Route:
`Route::resource('clients', 'ClientController');`

ClientController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Client;

class ClientController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * Create a new controller instance
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $clients = Client::where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->get();

        return view('clients.index', [
            'clients' => $clients,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('clients.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'organization' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

        //Create the task

        $request->user()->clients()->create([
            'organization' => $request->name,
        ]);

        return redirect('/clients');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        $client = Client::find($id);
        return view('clients.show', compact($client));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

View (clients/show.blade.php):

```
@extends('admin_template')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <strong>Organization: </strong> {{ $client->organization }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I can do `dd($client)` in my controller (show) and see that the data I need is there so it is fetching it from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        //
        $client = Client::find($id);
        return view('clients.show', compact('client'));
    }
```

compact method hold the variable with quote without $ sign and you will get the variable in the view as **$client**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
return view('clients.index', [    // the view you are referring is clients.index
            'clients' => $clients,
        ]);
```

and here you are trying to get the data in **clients/show.blade.php**. How is it possible.

If you want to access $client in clients/show.blade.php then you have to change the view name in **return view()** method

Comment: I think you are looking at my main index method in the controller right?  The `public function show($id)` points to the right one but I still get the error

Comment: Check the name of view in return view() and the file name in which you are trying to get the values

Answer (score 0):

First thinks,

1. In controller used variable "clients" , in view used variable "client" missing "s" in view variable.
2. if clients is array , You have to use "for" loop view page.

i think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this 
        `return view('clients.index')->with('clients', $clients);`
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
        `return view('clients.index')->with('clients', $clients);`
**In clients/show.blade.php**
use like this

```
@foreach($clients as $row)
 $row->your col name;
@endforeach
```